# Where was Ani Achola the night of the murder?

Tags: 13-reasons-why

During the third season of *13 Reasons Why*, where was Ani Achola at the night of the murder?

What did she really do that night?

I realized that the story she told the police was false to protect Clay but I didn't understand if she went to bed immediately after the game.

Comment: May be there will be another season to show that

Comment: She said she did go to her bed because she was scared. Her mother confirmed that too - When Mrs Walker asked Mrs Achola where her daughter was that night, she replied with something like "Here in her bed, away from all the drama". Mrs Achola did not know where she was earlier, but being the woman she is, she would have checked if her daughter was in her room that night or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ani had already lied to her mother had sneaked out of the house to be at the homecoming coming. When things started to get messy and she was asked by Bryce to leave, she ran back to her home, hid her stained clothes and washed her hands (both stained from paint) to remove any sign that she was a part of the HO protest, and went back to her bed before there was any chance for her to find out that she was out at night.